# ember-cli duplicate config location setting for rootUrl and locationType?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using ember-cli and I noticed two places that seemingly serve the same purpose.

in **config/environment.js**

```
  var ENV = {
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: ''
```

in **app/router.js**

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  rootUrl: config.baseUrl
  location: config.locationType,
});
```

Should these always be the same? What's the distinguishing factor between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a moment and look at `router.js`, notice the `import config from './config/environment';`?

The distinguishing factor between them is that `config/environment.js` is the module where all your settings are defined and `router.js` is making use of what was defined by calling `config.baseUrl` that depending on the environment that you are running your app will give a different result, it allows you to specify different values depending on the env

```
if (environment === 'production') {
  ENV.baseURL = '/';
}
```

and

```
if (environment === 'production') {
  ENV.baseURL = '/beta/';
}
```

So when you run `ember build` or `ember build --environment production` you don't have to manually modify every file you defined a baseUrl in.

Comment: ah of course! thank you for opening my eyes. IMO the names should be the same in both files

Comment: @user391986 The names can be whatever you want them to be, since in environment.js we export default you can `import myOwnConfigName from './config/environment;`